# Access Server Root in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to access some servers at work through Powershell because I find that it makes everything easier. The setup is something like this:

```
\\[Server1]\Folder 1
\\[Server1]\Folder 2
\\[Server1]\Folder 3
\\[Server2]\Folder 1
\\[Server2]\Folder 2
\\[Server3]\Folder 1
```

I would like a way to switch from one of these folders to any other without having to either set up functions to change the directory for me or having to manually type in the server name and folder to make the switch.

The problem I'm running into when I try to `cd ..` from, say, `\\[Server 1]\Folder 1` is

```
cd : Cannot find path 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::' because it does not exist.
```

If I try `cd '\\[Server Name]'` or `cd '\\[Server Name]\'` I get

```
cd : Cannot find path '\\[Server Name]' because it does not exist.
```

or

```
cd : Cannot find path '\\[Server Name]\' because it does not exist.
```

I can browse the 'root folder' in explorer and easily select any of the sub-folders I want, but would like to be able to do the same in Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

It is because that valid UNC is in format \server\share. Windows explorer somehow (I do not know how) query server for all it shares.
There is a comandlet for querying shares on server [Get-NtfShares](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj603101%28v=wps.620%29.aspx) but it applies to Windows Server 2012

**UPDATE**
I found how you can do this by WMI and powershell just type:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -computerName HostName
```

More information on this article: [Scripting File Shares with Microsoft PowerShell](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_wmi_shares.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately, this appears to require access to PSRemoting or some other remote command functionality. Would be nice if there was an alternative that allowed you to get the listing without any special privileges or services, just like you can from Explorer.